# Adding nodes by button and IE doesn't display node text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, internet-explorer-11

I'm using the [jstree plugin](http://www.jstree.com/) in the latest version.

I have a tree to which I add, rename and remove nodes by buttons.
On Firefox and Chrome there is no problem, but on IE there are two problems when the buttons are clicked fast one by one.

When the Add group button is clicked, then nodes are visible in the tree, but not for all nodes their text is displayed.
With the Rename node button is clicked on node few times one by one, then node loses the selected to edit text.

Simple code to reproduction:

```
.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q0rfrbcx/4/

That'a how it looks like on my IE11:

[image]

Comment: Your jsfiddle example is not working in chrome.

Comment: I corrected the link. This one works in my latest chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin author fixed this issue: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/commit/9d17744c82c07b695a2cd224542aa1c2148a452c

Answer (score 0):

commenting out

setTimeout(function () {
        ref.edit(node);
    }, 300);

seems to solve the issue for me in IE. But i cannot get it to work on my chrome(may be different issue). 


*Even the demo at jstree have the same issue in IE.*